# I want to install nuxt js on my pc but the error is showing every time

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to install nuxt js on my pc but the error is showing every time

> $ npm init nuxt-app project-name
> '"create-nuxt-app"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\mahmu\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ""create-nuxt-app" "project-name""

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\mahmu\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-11T13_59_01_781Z-debug.log

I dont Know why its happening

Comment: Try with `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`. Also, are you using Node 16?

Comment: What's in `C:\Users\mahmu\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-11T13_59_01_781Z-debug.log`?

Answer (score 2):

Try "npm init nuxt-app@latest"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It installs create-nuxt-app if not already installed, so this is probably the OPs error.